# Mongodb could not find user "user@database"

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to allow a mongo user to connect to a mongo database, but regardless of what roles I give the user, the authentication fails with this error in the logs:

```
2019-08-09T17:03:05.486+0000 I ACCESS   [conn13] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for username on dbname from client 127.0.0.1:38790 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user username@dbname
2019-08-09T17:03:05.488+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13] end connection 127.0.0.1:38790 (0 connections now open)
```

Here are the contents of `/etc/mongodb.conf`

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

auth=true
```

And here is how I created the user:

```
db.createUser({
  user: "username",
  pwd: "secret",
  roles: [
    { role: "userAdmin", db: "dbname" },
    { role: "dbAdmin",   db: "dbname" },
    { role: "readWrite", db: "dbname" }
  ]
});
```

I also granted the `dbOwner` role to the user on the database `dbname`. What is happening here? Why can't I connect to the database if the user is the owner and has read/write privileges? Do I have to create a user with the name `username@dbname`?

EDIT: Just tried adding a user with the username `username@dbname`, but that user also fails to connect.

I can also connect to mongo with the same command minus the `/dbname` at the end and then run `use dbname`. I have no clue why this would work, but connecting directly wouldn't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue is that the database user is being created on the `admin` database instead of `dbname`.

Omitting the `/dbname` from the connection string / mongo shell / etc. means the connection string will authenticate to the `admin` database. Quoting the docs:

> If '/database' is not specified and the connection string includes
>   credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin database

(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#components).

If `/dbname` is defined, then the connection string will authenticate against `dbname` unless the [authSource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource) parameter is configured to specify the database in which the user resides.

You can confirm that this is the case by either adding `authSource=admin` to the connection string or `--authenticationDatabase admin` to the [mongo shell command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-authenticationdatabase).

Alternatively, you can use `db.getUsers()` to see the database in which a user was created.

Comment: The issue was related to `authenticationDatabase`. For some reason my users all got created on the `test` database (which I didn't create).

Answer (score 5):

I faced with the same error and my solution was adding `?authSource=admin` to the end of the connection string:

```sh
MONGODB_URI="mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/db_name?authSource=admin"
```