# Can't connect to mongodb container when i add path to a database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I’m running mongoDB as a docker container locally, and I initiate a database creation when starting the container. But I can’t seem to connect to the database from my nodejs application when I add path to the dB. For example i can connect when I use “mongoDB://admin:password@localhost:27017” but not when I use “mongoDB://admin:password@localhost:27017/myDB”.

I'm running the container with docker-compose. Also when I log the output of running the mongo container I see a failure message that says:

```
"result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"admin\" for db \"journalDB\""}}
```

JournalDB is the name of the db i want to connect to, and i want to be able to connect to it from my nodejs application like so:

```
mongoose
.connect("mongoDB://admin:password@localhost:27017/journalDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
```

I have read the answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434521/mongodb-could-not-find-user-userdatabase/57436441) and this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource) , but I feel they have only explained the possible problem, but have not helped me fix it.
I would really appreciate it if there's a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try
.connect("mongoDB://admin:password@localhost:27017/journalDB?authSource=admin" ...

Comment: Oh, this worked perfectly!  I think I have been misunderstanding the answer in the similar question I shared as well as the documentation. They all mentioned adding authSource=admin but I had thought they meant replacing admin with my authentication db which I thought was supposed to be journalDB. Thank you so much for your clear answer!